# If parent of a serializable class doesn't implement serializable, parent will be serialized automatically?

Tags: java, serialization

This confusion is created by Java documentation at Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html
It says: " To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the subtype **may assume responsibility** for saving and restoring the state of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package fields. The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the class's state. It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this is not the case. The error will be detected at runtime.

***During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the class***. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is serializable. The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored from the stream. "

When we are talking about serializable interface we are talking about automatic serialization mechanism in action. If it would have been custom we would have been talking about Externalizable interface. So when oracle doc says "To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the subtype **may assume responsibility** " looks like this is part of automatic serialization mechanism. My question is: How to interpret Oracle documentation on Java? Subclass taking responsibility is automatic or a developer of subclass will have to write the code to serialize parent which is not implementing serializable interface?

Answer (score 0):

As the doc say: you **may** assume responsibility.

This means that by default these values will be established by calling `super()` no argument constructor.

It is however possible that you **may need** these to be serialized (and deserialized) in which case the responsibility is yours.

Specs are close to legal (well bounded) language.